# Objective C copy array to another array with index 1

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, copy

I have an array with 1 object in it at index 0 if I am correct. Now I would like to copy an array with x objects into my first array with 1 object, leaving the object there as it is so:

array 1: objectA

array 2: object1, object 2, object 3

Now Array 1 = copy array 2 to array 1

Array 1: objectA, object1, object2, object 3....

How can I do that?

Comment: Read the documentation for `NSArray` and you will find your answer faster than asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   array1 = [array1 arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `NSMutableArray` for `array1` then just do

```
[array1 addObjectsFromArray:array2];
```

If you need to convert an NSArray into a mutable one, which is advisable if you plan to do even more modifications on the array, then do

```
NSMutableArray mArray1 = [array1 mutableCopy];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray mArray1 = [NSMutablearray arrayWithArray:array1];
```

For more details about dealing with Arrays see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html or https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSArray respectively.